# Send back json to client side

Tags: python, json, web-services, post, cherrypy

I just started developing with cherrypy, so I am struggling a little bit.
In client side I am selecting some data, converting it to json and sending to server side via post method. Then I am doing a few operations with json and finally I want to send it back to client side. So the question is how to return modified json to the client side (browser).

Server side:

```
  @cherrypy.expose
  def drawChart(self):
        __test = cherrypy.request.body.read().strip()
        logging.debug(__test)
        #...some operations with data
```

Client side:

```
function send(JsonArray){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/drawChart',
            type: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: console.log("Success!"),
            data: JsonArray
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change to this line instead of what you have...

```
            success: drawChart,
```

EDIT:
Oh - and change your handler to this:

```
def drawChart(self, data):
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use [CherryPy JSON tools](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basics.html#dealing-with-json).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import cherrypy


config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 8080,
    'server.thread_pool' : 8
  }
}

class App:

  @cherrypy.expose
  def index(self):
    return '''<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
        <title>CherryPy demo</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
          $.ajax({
            'type'        : 'POST',
            'dataType'    : 'JSON',
            'contentType' : 'application/json',
            'url'         : '/someendpoint',
            'data'        : JSON.stringify({'foo': ['bar']}),
            'success'     : function(response)
            {
              console.log(response);
            }
          });
        </script>
      </head>
      </html>
    '''

  @cherrypy.expose
  @cherrypy.tools.json_in()
  @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
  def someendpoint(self):
    yourDict = cherrypy.request.json
    yourDict['foo'].append('baz')

    return yourDict


if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/', config)
```

Comment: It is okay if I am sending data like this {x: "111"}, but if I am sending json like this: {"Coordinates":[{"x":"892850686394369 ","y":"4c189d55d5a2b4d682647bfcc9e5827112abfe7c"},{"x":"892850686394430 ","y":"b1c8238337a3e17352718a46ca0a76a7e196adfd"}]} how should look my method in python?

Comment: @Rokas.ma you can pass arbitrary JSON data both directions. Take `cherrypy.request.json`, do you transformation, return result from your handler.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is:

```
 @cherrypy.expose
    def drawChart(self, coordinates):
        cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        listOfCoordiantes = randomData(coordinates)
        return json.dumps(dict(Coordinates=listOfCoordiantes))
```