# CherryPy and JSON: Sending list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, post, cherrypy

I would like to send a list of dictionaries from a web browser to a server running CherryPy. What should the code in CherryPy be to receive it?

### JavaScript in Web Browser

```
var listOfDictionaries = {
    "Coordinates":
    [
        {"x":"892850686394369 ","y":"4c189d55d5a2b4d682647bfcc9e5827112abfe7c"},
        {"x":"892850686394430 ","y":"b1c8238337a3e17352718a46ca0a76a7e196adfd"}
    ]
};

$.post('drawChart', listOfDictionaries,
    function (data) {
        $("#title").html(data['title']);
    });
```

Data that I am sending via an HTTP POST:

```
{"Coordinates":[{"x":"892850686394369 ","y":"4c189d55d5a2b4d682647bfcc9e5827112abfe7c"},{"x":"892850686394430 ","y":"b1c8238337a3e17352718a46ca0a76a7e196adfd"}]}
```

### CherryPy method on Web Server

```py
@cherrypy.expose
def drawChart(self, x, y):
    cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    return json.dumps(dict(title="x: %s" x))
```

Comment: What d you mean receive it? Receive it where? The browser?

Comment: @IanAuld I am sending list of dictionaries via post method from client side (browser) and the question is that how should function look in server side (cherrypy) to receive data (list of dictionaries)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to receive JSON in a POST request in CherryPy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743769/how-to-receive-json-in-a-post-request-in-cherrypy)

Comment: @IanAuld I looked there before posting, but there is not what I need, I did not find solution there

Comment: http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basics.html#dealing-with-json

Comment: and what do u want to say with that link? It does not help

Comment: That's the documentation for the framework you are using on how to accept JSON data from POST requests. It's highly relevant to your question and in fact shows you exactly what you need to do.

Comment: You shouldn't ask the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427742/send-back-json-to-client-side) over again.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late answer, I solved this problem like this:

client side (browser):

```
    coordinates = {'coordinates': coordinates}
    $.post('/drawChart', coordinates, function (data) {
                    createGraph((data['Coordinates']));
                });
```

server side (python):

```
@cherrypy.expose
def drawChart(self, coordinates):
    cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    listOfCoordiantes = randomData(coordinates)
    return json.dumps(dict(Coordinates=listOfCoordiantes))
```